# DismissModalViewControllerAnimated?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, modal-dialog, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've been looking for hours to solve my problem. Right now my program is set as a page control with a UIScrollView. So I looked at a tutorial on adding an in-app email (http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-in-app-email/).

Everything works out well until I want to cancel an email, or send the mail, the log says it did the method fine, however when i do the

`[self DismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

it will dismiss to the mainwindow.xib, however, I want it to dismiss back to the secondcontrollerview where the email function and button resides obviously.

What am i missing? Hope someone could help ^-^,

Comment: What is `self` in your example? Are you calling `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` on the `MFMailComposeViewController` or on the view controller which presented it? Also did you actually capitalize the 'D' in that method name in your code?

Answer (score 0):

simply .. if you are present your mailController from seconedControllerView your app will return back to it when you dismiss the mailController.